# How to find the variables needed to create a function in R?

Tags: r, function, arguments, rstudio

I'm using R and RStudio.  Often I write code and then realize I would like that code to be a function.  Here's a very simplified illustration:

The code I might write (not a great example, but serves the purpose):

```
aSqr <- a * a
bCub <- b^3
c4th <- c^4
result <- aSqr + bCub + c4th
```

I then decide to put this into a function which requires identifying that a, b, and c would need to be arguments to the function, but not aSqr, bCub, and c4th.  Is there a way to highlight code in RStudio and have it identify the variables which would need to be passed as arguments?  In this example, the arguments are obvious.  In the code I actually write, it's not so obvious.

So I would end up with a function like:

```
myFunction <- function(a, b, c){
    aSqr <- a * a
    bCub <- b^3
    c4th <- c^4
    return(aSqr + bCub + c4th)
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from the description.  If you want to get the objects already created, use `ls` with `pattern` i.e. `ls(pattern = '^a|b|c$')`

Comment: @akrun I think the question is can you get RStudio to recognize arguments needed for a custom function based on pre-existing code.

Comment: RStudio has a shortcut for this. Highlight the code, press Ctrl + Alt + X.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Stefan's comment with some images of what it looks like:

Step 1. Write your code.

```
aSqr <- a * a
bCub <- b^3
c4th <- c^4
result <- aSqr + bCub + c4th
```

Step 2. Highlight what you want your function to be and push Ctrl + Alt + X (Windows) or    Cmd + Option + X (Max). Alternatively, go to the menu Code > Extract Function. Give it a name.

[image: Extract function]

Step 3. You have a function!

```
myFunction <- function(a, b, c) {
  aSqr <- a * a
  bCub <- b^3
  c4th <- c^4
  result <- aSqr + bCub + c4th
}
```

In your case, you likely want to add `return(result)` after the last line so that your function returns a value that you can assign.